# How to call method in filter datagrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, datagrid

The problem is I can't call method to use in filter.

In sameple_grid.rb

I have a sample method that query all records after join

```
def method_sameple(field, operation, value)
  ids = Model2.joins(:model2_model3s).where("score#{operation} ? AND model3_id= ?", value, field).ids
  Model1.joins(:model2s).where(model2: { id: ids})
end
```

then I have a filter that call `method_sample`

```
filter(:name, :dynamic, select: [[name, id]], header: -> { 'Name' }) do |(field, operation, value), scope|
   #mehtod need to call in here!
end
```

Comment: I have used datagrid gem for filtering and I have a method for using in other filters. I don't want to write the same query in other filters

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(:name, :dynamic, select: [[name, id]], header: -> { 'Name' }) do |(field, operation, value), scope|
   #mehtod need to call in here!
   method_return = self.method_sameple(your, params, of_method)
end
```

this is a standard way to call method on instance of model(method call work inside another method).

but there is not enough info to understand in which way you using filters. need more context to understand you problem.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.